# Derivative of constants? (Applications of Integrals)

Tags: calculus

I'm working on a list of problems from a chapter titled "Applications of Integrals" (area, volume, work etc.) and I have this problem:

$f(x)=(2+\frac{9}{2})^3$ find $f'(x)$

As far as I know, this notation refers to the derivative of $f(x)$, yet this just be zero since it is only constants. I'm guessing there is more to this problem than  that considering that it's surrounded by integrals on my worksheet, so am I missing  something? Unless $f'(x)$ does not refer to a derivative? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: " I'm guessing there is more to this problem than that "  Nope, there isn't.

Comment: Maybe it was a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the book made a typo and there is supposed to be an $x$ in there somewhere.

Or maybe the book wants you to prove that all the rules of derivatives still hold.

By chain rule if $j(x) = 2; g(x) = x + \frac 92; h(x) = x^3$ so $f(x) = h(g(j(x)))$ then

$j'(x) = 0; g'(x) = 1; h'(x) = 3x^2$ so by chain rule:

$f'(x)= [h(g(j(x)))]' = h'(g(j(x)))g'(j(x))h'(x) = 3(2+\frac 92)^2\cdot 1\cdot 0 = 0$

But  that was silly.

I bet it was a typo.

====

But obviously you are right $f(x) = (2 +\frac 92)^3 = (\frac {13}2)^3 = 2460.375$ is a constant so $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking something similar about the chain rule, but yeah it still results in zero. All right, I'll be sure to ask around on Monday, I appreciate the explanation, though.

Comment: It's not a *bad* exercise to prove that different rules will still apply when attack by different methods.  It's a bit excessive to apply the chain rule to *everything* but you can.

Comment: Yet another option: trick question designed to make you get distracted by the expression and do lots of unnecessary work! "But it's just a constant" might be the intended correct answer.

Comment: Yes, that is actually more likely.  And it is .... just a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The only two possibilities I can think of is that there is a variable you have misread as a number, or $f$ is elsewhere defined in terms of some expression, and you're being asked to find what its derivative is when that expression is equal to $(2+\frac92)^2$. Normally, images are discouraged, but one might help in this case.

Comment: THird option.  The book made a typo.